# Create multiple files with filenames from bs4

Tags: python, html, beautifulsoup

How do I write each `<a>` line into it own file and use H2 as filename???

```
import re
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import os

data = '<html><div class="colors"> <a href="/green"> <div class="values"> GRN <h2 class="tester"> Green </h2> </div> </a> <a href="/purple"> <div class="values"> PURP <h2 class="tester"> Purple </h2> </div> </a> <a href="/orange"> <div class="values"> ORNG <h2 class="tester"> Orange </h2> </div> </a> </div><html>'
soup = BeautifulSoup(data, "html.parser")

colors = soup.find("div", {"class": "colors"})

for lines in colors:
    docs = lines.find("h2").text.strip()
    file = open('C:/Users/Admin/Desktop/'+str(doc)+'.txt', 'a', encoding='utf-8')
    file.write(str(lines))
    file.close()
```

Looking for results with the filename and html contents inside.

Green.txt
`<a href="/green"> <div class="values"> GRN <h2 class="tester"> Green </h2> </div> </a>`

Purple.txt
`<a href="/purple"> <div class="values"> PURP <h2 class="tester"> Purple </h2> </div> </a>`

Orange.txt
`<a href="/orange"> <div class="values"> ORNG <h2 class="tester"> Orange </h2> </div> </a>`

Answer (score 0):

Hope I got it right you have to iterate the `<a>` instead the `<div>` with class *colors* to get your goal:

```
for e in soup.select('.colors a'):
    name = e.h2.get_text(strip=True)
    html = str(e)
    file = open(name+'.txt', 'a', encoding='utf-8')
    file.write(html)
    file.close()
```

##### Example

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import os

data = '<html><div class="colors"> <a href="/green"> <div class="values"> GRN <h2 class="tester"> Green </h2> </div> </a> <a href="/purple"> <div class="values"> PURP <h2 class="tester"> Purple </h2> </div> </a> <a href="/orange"> <div class="values"> ORNG <h2 class="tester"> Orange </h2> </div> </a> </div><html>'
soup = BeautifulSoup(data, "html.parser")
    
for e in soup.select('.colors a'):
    name = e.h2.get_text(strip=True)
    html = str(e)
    file = open(name+'.txt', 'a', encoding='utf-8')
    file.write(html)
    file.close()
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `find_all` method to extract to get all `a` tag and iterate over to get filename from `h2` tag and you can get desire output:

```
links=colors.find_all("a")
for link in links:
    fname=link.find("h2").get_text(strip=True)
     with open(fname+".txt","w") as wr:
        wr.write(str(link))
```